# How to make Terminal settings to default?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have accidentally set `don't show menus` in Terminal preferences and cannot open preferences anymore. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type: `gnome-terminal --show-menubar` in the terminal.
You will still have to change the settings back, but you can reach the menu to do that.

Like with most applications, you can get this kind of information from `man gnome-terminal`

(`man application_name`)

Answer (score 2):

Try right click at terminal desktop and click show menu bar